# SQL script runs on Query Builder but not on execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

this is very wiered, I hope you can help me out here.
I'm working with Visual Studio 2019, creating a small app for my company to manage licenses. I have a SQL query script which works on the query builder but not on Execution. Here is the script:

```
SELECT        WorkstationID, Vendor, SoftwareName 
FROM            Licenses 
WHERE        (Vendor LIKE '%' + @Vendor + '%') OR (@Vendor IS NULL)
```

When I run the script on the query builder it works fine and I get the resaults. When I execute it under the app (or under "Preview Data" on Visual studio) I get an error message says: "The parameterized query '(@Vendor nvarchar(max) Select expects the parameter '@Vendor', which was not supplied."

I'll just add that the purpose of my query is to get rows with a specific words, or if the user didn't provide any text - it will return all the rows.

Thanks!

Comment: We need to see the actual vb.net code to be able to help you.

Comment: Think the structure of your parameter isn’t right.  Shouldn’t the % be in the parameter value and skip the string concatenation altogether

Comment: Hursey it works either way